# how to open a pipe delimited csv file in excel using java

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file that has Pipe delimited, But when i open it using excel the whole data in the csv file gets into a single cell. 
without changing the pipe separated to comma separated. The CSV file should properly get the values and display in co responding cell

Comment: How exactly does Java fit in the equation?

Comment: All the data in the csv file gets into a single cell of the excel. Like Name| Phone NO Sivan|12345 Easwer|98765 the whole thing gets into a single cell, but it sholud come in proper row and column in excel

Comment: can you share snapshot of the csv file in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You must choose delimiter while opening the file. Default delimiter is tabs. But check your excel settings and add comma and any other symbol as delimiter. There could be some issue with your csv file as well.

For now follow these steps:

1. Click on Data menu on top.

[image]

2. Click on From Text / CSV button:

[image]

3. Now explore your file and open it.
   [image]
4. Now choose delimiter of your choice and preview data and load it.
   [image]

Basically you can analyze your csv here for any issues as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to change the delimiter of excel using java

Comment: No! you can't change delimiter of excel using java. As csv is very plain comma separated format and it don't allow any such control over the client application you are using to parse and view the csv file.